# SwiftSoup wrap text in body to a div

Tags: swift, swiftsoup

I have a HTML that I would like to manipulate with SwiftSoup but I have no idea how to wrap the texts inside body with a div
Here's an example input:

```
<body>
text <b>not</b> in a div
<div>text already in a div</div>
</body>
```

The output I would like to achieve:

```
<body>
<div>text <b>not</b> in a div</div>
<div>text already in a div</div>
</body>
```